# HighStock: Add series dynamically introduce gap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Adding series dynamically introduce gap in the existing series.

http://jsfiddle.net/anandc999/6XRuY/

Steps to reproduce
1. load the above url
2. click any where in the candlestick (OHLC)
3. move the mouse with in the candlestick
4. click again with in the candlestick chart
Observe a new series is added but a gap is introduced in the existing Volume and OHLC series.

How to add series without a gap?
Already tried gapsize and connectNulls but doesnt work. Can anybody help?

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) axis in Highstock. This option forces to display points evenly on a chart, so when new points are added - it recalculates position of each points.

To prevent that set ordinal: false, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/6XRuY/7/

Code:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false  
},
```